# Never ending Win32 Message loop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have the following code:

```
MSG mssg;

// run till completed
while (true) {

    // is there a message to process?
    while(PeekMessage( &mssg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        // dispatch the message
        TranslateMessage(&mssg);
        DispatchMessage(&mssg);
    }
    if(mssg.message == WM_QUIT){
        break;
    }
    // our stuff will go here!!
    Render();
    listeners->OnUpdate();
}
```

Once it enters the inner loop with peekmessage it does not exit until the application is closed. Thus if I place a breakpoint at Render() and OnUpdate(), they will never be called during the lifetime of the application.

This runs contrary to what I'm being told [here](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/writing_the_game_loop.htm) and [here](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial9/A-Win32/dx9A4.aspx#still). How do I do this properly?

Comment: Im requesting this closed, I commented out handling of WM_PAINT resulting in the message loop behaving as expected..

Comment: As an aside do you realise that if you DON'T return 0 from your WM_PAINT handler then it will just queue another WM_PAINT message and hence your loop will do nothing but handle WM_PAINTs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical game loop has this form:

```
MSG mssg;
bool notdone = true;
// run till completed
while (  notdone  ) {

        // is there a message to process?
        if (PeekMessage( &mssg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if (mssg.message == WM_QUIT) notdone = false;

            // dispatch the message
            TranslateMessage(&mssg);
            DispatchMessage(&mssg);
        } else {
            // our stuff will go here!!
            Render();
            listeners->OnUpdate();
        }
}
```

Comment: this makes no difference to my predicament, placing a breakpoint in the else brackets shows that if(PeekMessage(...)) is always true in this case

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, I fixed a bug. Check it out.

Comment: Nick: Replace `if(PeekMessage(..` with `while(PeekMessage..`; It's more correct for Tom's usage, which is a game. If you parse one message for every time you render or change game state, events starts clogging up. That's no good.

Comment: @Mads Elvheim, no user code will be called until the message queue is empty. Read the code more carefully ;)

Comment: ... actually the 2 loop forms are equivalent.