# Creating two windows in one app

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm learning `C++` and I have some questions. Some researches at msdn didn't help me. I wanna create two windows in one app. One window - dialog with options and another for graphic output. Here is the code that I use. But I have some problems with it:

- Second window (for graphic) does not react at close, minimize, iconic buttons presses.
- Message Boxes, when appear, are not in focus and not react at any mouse clicks, but in this time main window works fine.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{   
    InitCommonControls();   

    if(FAILED(DialogWindow_OnCreate(hInstance)))
            return 1;

    if(FAILED(GraphicWindow_OnCreate(hInstance)))
            return 1;

    MSG msg;
    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(MSG));
    while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
            while(PeekMessageA(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {       
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);      
            }

            OnUpdate();
    }

    GraphicWindow_OnClose();        

    return 0;
}
```

Creation of main window (Dialog):

```
 HRESULT DialogWindow_OnCreate(HINSTANCE hInst)
    {
        g_hDialogWindow = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, DialogWindow_WndProc);

        if(!g_hDialogWindow)
            return E_NOTIMPL;

        UpdateWindow(g_hDialogWindow);

        return S_OK;
    }
```

Main window proc (Dialog):

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogWindow_WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);     

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {           
            g_hDialogWindow = hWnd;

            // Some init actions ...

            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }   
    case WM_COMMAND:        
        int wmId, wmEvent;
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        switch(wmEvent)
        {
        case NULL: // Menu used
            {
                switch(wmId)
                {
                case IDC_BTN_1:
                    {
                        DialogWindow_OnBtn1();
                        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Some message", "Some title", MB_OK);
                        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
                    } break;
                case IDC_BTN_2:
                    {
                        DialogWindow_OnBtn2();
                        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
                    } break;

                // ...

                    case IDCANCEL:
                    {
                        // Close window
                        DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, wParam, lParam);
                    } break;
                    case IDOK:
                    {
                        // Close window
                    DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, wParam, lParam);
                    } break;
                }
            }
        }
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:        
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        break;  
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;      
    }

return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Second window (Graphic) creation:

```
HRESULT GraphicWindow_OnCreate(HINSTANCE hInst)
{
    HWND g_hGraphicWindow = NULL;

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style              = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = GraphicWindow_WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInst;
    wcex.hIcon              = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APP_ICO));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = 0;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = _T("MyApp");
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL)); 

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if(dwError != ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "GraphicWindow: RegisterClass() failed!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);            
        }
    }

    // Set window's initial size, but it might be changed later
    int nDefaultWidth = 320;
    int nDefaultHeight = 240;
    RECT rc;
    SetRect(&rc, 0, 0, nDefaultWidth, nDefaultHeight);
    AdjustWindowRect(&rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);    

    // Create the window
    g_hGraphicWindow = CreateWindowA("MyApp", "GraphicWindow", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                      CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, (rc.right - rc.left), (rc.bottom - rc.top), 0,
                      0, hInst, 0);
    if(!g_hGraphicWindow)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "GraphicWindow: CreateWindow() failed!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
    }

    UpdateWindow(g_hGraphicWindow); 

    return S_OK;
}
```

Graphic window proc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GraphicWindow_WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam); 

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case VK_RETURN:         
            // Some actions ...         
            break;              
        case VK_ESCAPE:         
            // Some actions ...             
            break;  
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;    
    case WM_CLOSE:      
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);      
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Where is my problem? Help me, please.

Comment: Sounds like you want [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632591(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm not sure what you're asking for is possible. A modal dialog blocks all interaction with an application.

Comment: Too much code. Learn to narrow the problem down to a specific code block, then post just enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Mike W, i'm sorry for a lot of code, but i can't localize my problem - that is why i'm here.

Comment: Use debugging technique. For example, put a break point in case WM_CLOSE: and tell us if you hit it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan He won't use a regular loop, and it may be a legit choice. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1815144/1374704

Comment: Thanks. This -> stackoverflow.com/a/1815144/1374704 loop is better then my. But problem is not solved. WM_CLOSE not sended to 'Graphic' window. Going to learn more about MDI window ...

Comment: @Slinner Why do you think you need a `PeekMessage` loop? Do you want your process to run hot? Surely you need a `GetMessage` based loop that can block.

Comment: @David Heffernan I need to update my WinSock2 socket.

Comment: @Slinner Fine. Why does that mean you cannot use `GetMessage`? Anyway, that's not the main issue here. Try to solve the main problem with the most standard message loop (as per my answer) and then worry about the socket code. When you get that far, still use `GetMessage` though!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the follow comments to make:

1. Do not call DefWindowProc in your dialog procedure. That could well be the main problem. See this example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996.aspx#modeless_box
2. Your message loop is somewhat bogus. More on that later.
3. You should not be calling ANSI functions. Remove all `A` suffixes. You'll need to prefix string literals with `L` to specify wide strings. For instance, `L"foo"`.
4. You should presumably pass the main window handle as `hWndParent` when you call `CreateDialog`. Otherwise, the modeless dailog will be unowned and so have its own taskbar button, and not appear always on top of the main window.
5. You should pass the main window handle as `hWnd` when you call `MessageBox`.

---

Looking in more detail at the message loop, you are not following the rules laid out in the documentation to [`CreateDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434.aspx), which states:

> To support keyboard navigation and other dialog box functionality, the message loop for the dialog box must call the IsDialogMessage function.

So your message loop should be:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if(!IsDialogMessage(g_hDialogWindow, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Note also that I switched to a `GetMessage` based loop. I don't think you need to run a hot loop for your needs. Using `GetMessage` allows your app's main thread to yield the CPU and block if it is idle.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, but it not solves the problem. The problem disappers only when i remove CreateDialog() func. and program creates only one window. I will learn msdn and then post here the answer.

Comment: Well, you still have to do what I said here. Anyway, when you can post an SSCCE we can for sure debug that.

Comment: @Slinner try the latest update. Your dialog proc is all wrong. Don't call DefWindowProc. A dialogue proc is not a window proc.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dialog Procedure, don't use `DefWindowProc`.

See: [Dialog Box Default Message Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#default_messages).

Comment: Thanks, but i alredy found it and wanted to post answer, but could not, because of my reputation. It solves all my problems!

Comment: All works fine, even with 'PeekMessage()' and ANSI func. ! Great thanks to all!

Comment: @David Heffernan, i wanna to learn:'Wide Chars instead of ANSI' - it very useful, and i will apply this, thanks. But PeekMessage() is more suitable for my case. I just wanted to say that these things did not relate to my problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan GetMessage may be better if he uses asynchronous Winsock, but if he's not, then the "blocking" functionality of GetMessage may be a problem.

Comment: GetMessage() waits for any message in message queue and then returns, instead of PeekMessage() - it returns immediately, even message queue is empty. With first case i can have unstable number of OnUpdate() calls.

Comment: @manuell PeekMessage won't help. Blocking sockets needs to be in separate thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And not blocking sockets will be fine in the unique thread, provided the message loop is not a black hole. Anyway, you and I would certainly NOT do it as the OP did, but, in my opinion, that's not the point.

Comment: @Slinner PeekMessage will run your CPU at 100%. It is the wrong thing. I can tell you that, but ultimately it is your choice.

Comment: @David Heffernan, Not, if i set freq of OnUpdate() calls with timeGetTime() and on remained time will call Sleep()

Comment: Your OnUpdate design is wrong. If async sockets, then you are good to go with standard message loop and sockets in main thread. If sockets are synchronous then you need a separate thread for the comms and blocking I/O.

Comment: You also need to consider the other message loops that run in your main thread. Modal dialogs and sizing loops. How are they going to call your OnUpdate function?

Comment: At this stage I do not see the need for multi-threading. I have only one message loop, and only he calls OnUpdate. Maybe I did not understand your question.